# How to translate a sql join query to typeorm using repositories?

Tags: inner-join, typeorm

I'm trying to write this query using repositories

```js
const d = await getManager().query(`SELECT exam.fiscal_code, exam.exam_id, exam.exam_date, exam.diagnosis 
        FROM exam INNER JOIN patient ON exam.fiscal_code = patient.fiscal_code 
        WHERE exam.doctor_id = ${req.user.doctorId} AND patient.name =${req.body.name} AND patient.surname =${req.body.surname}`)
```

Answer (score 0):

_cYou should first read [the documentation](https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/software_type_specific/in-app-browser/) as it's very clear on how do implement this.

First you will need to decorate your properties with `@ManyToOne` or `@ManyToMany` as explained in the docs.

Then just use the provided methods to write your query:

```
await createQueryBuilder('exam')
    .innerJoinAndSelect('exam', 'exam.patient', 'exam.fiscalCode = patient.fiscalCode')
    .where(...)
```

Or if you correctly decorated properties and provided inverse-side relation you could just do:

```
await createQueryBuilder('exam')
    .innerJoinAndSelect('exam.fiscalCode', 'fiscalCode')
    .where(...)
```

Next time you should provide a more precise description of your code so people can understand better what you are doing and give a more precise answer. Since there isn't just one way to do things.

Please note that I used *camelCase* instead of *snake_case* for the columns in the `innerJoinAndSelect` method. This is because TypeORM expects the name of the Javascript properties and not the SQL ones. I don't know if you name them that way but you should anyway.